# Change data in modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<tbody>
    <tr th:each="worker: ${workersList}">
        <td th:text="${worker.id}"></td>
        <td th:text="${worker.name}"></td>
        <td th:text="${worker.email}"></td>
        <td>
            <a href="#editModal" class="btn tooltipped modal-trigger" data-position="top" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Edit">
                <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <!-- Edit Modal Structure -->
    <div id="editModal" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4 th:text="${worker.email}"></h4>
            <p>A bunch of text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-grey btn-flat">Update</a>
            <a href="#" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn-flat">Close</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</tbody>
```

Hello, I've a problem with upper code. I need to get actual clicked worker from list of all workers inside this modal. But I got always the same first worker from list. How to change it in order to get different workers depend on who I'll click? 
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must pass your data to modal, for example using data attribute:

```
<a href="#editModal" class="btn tooltipped modal-trigger" data-position="top" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Edit" th:attr="data-email=${worker.email}"><i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i></a>
```

in your modal definition, store `modal-email` id:

```
<div id="editModal" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4 id="modal-email"></h4>
        <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-grey btn-flat">Update</a>
        <a href="#" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn-flat">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

then in javascript:

```
$('#editModal').modal({
    ready: function(modal, trigger) {
        var button = $(trigger);
        var email = button.data('email');
        $('#modal-email').html(email);     
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not bootstrap modal, it's materializecss modal. It cannot open in your case.

Comment: I changed the code, it must be something like this.

Comment: Ok, but this ->  data-email="${worker.email}"  cannot work, because I got a text {worker.email}, there must be sth another to assign it in thymeleaf

Comment: yes, it seems you must use ```th:attr="data-email=#{worker.email}"```. correctd in code.

Comment: Ok, I've done it, like this -> th:attr="data-email=${investor.email}"